# Cache in Grails

Tags: grails, ehcache

I am facing an issue with second level cache in grails.The following are the configurations I am following

**DataSource.groovy**

```
    hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = true     
        cache.use_query_cache = true  
        cache.provider_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
    }
```

**FirmClient.groovy**

```
    static mapping = {
      cache true
    }
```

**FirmClientController.groovy**

```
    def t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    def firmClient = FirmClient?.findAll(query,[cache:true])  
    println "time take for Firm client list>>>>>> ${System.currentTimeMillis()-t1}"
```

**conf/ehcache.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <defaultCache name="default" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600" overflowToDisk="true"/>
    <cache name="FirmClient" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600" overflowToDisk="true"/>
  </ehcache>
```

1. First issue is in tmpdir, FirmClient.data is not having anydata.How I can dump data into FirmClient.data
2. Second issue is when ever I am hitting the query first time the time in millseconds is   more then for second hit with same params gradually it is decreasing.but if the query is cached I think it should show the time period as zero.

Can any one help me how second level cache works and how I can resolve the above Issues?

Comment: There won't be anything written to tmpdir/FirmClient.data unless more than 10000 (`maxElementsInMemory`) elements are returned by the query.